# Why BlocProvider Gets this two errors with null-safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, dart-null-safety

Error No.1 :

```
error: 'Null' doesn't conform to the bound 'BlocBase<Object?>' of the type parameter 'T'. (type_argument_not_matching_bounds
```

Error No.2 :

```
error: Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.
Tried to infer 'Null' for 'T' which doesn't work:
  Type parameter 'T' is declared to extend 'BlocBase<Object?>' producing 'BlocBase<Object?>'.
The type 'Null' was inferred from:
  Parameter 'create' declared as     'T Function(BuildContext)'
                     but argument is 'Null Function(BuildContext)'.
```

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

(could_not_infer at [g_movies] lib\layout\movies_layout.dart:12)

> ```
>     class MoviesLayout extends StatelessWidget {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return BlocProvider(
>       create: (BuildContext context) {
>         MoviesCubit()..getTopRatedData();
>       },
>       child: BlocConsumer<MoviesCubit, MoviesStates>(
>         listener: (context, state) {},
>         builder: (context, state) {
>           return Scaffold(
>             appBar: AppBar(
>               title: Text(
>                 'GMovies',
>                 style: GoogleFonts.oswald(
>                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                   fontSize: 24,
>                   color: defaultColor,
>                 ),
>               ),
>               actions: [
>                 Padding(
>                   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
>                   child: CircleAvatar(
>                     radius: 20,
>                     child: IconButton(
>                       icon: Icon(Icons.person),
>                       onPressed: () {},
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                 ),
>               ],
>             ),
>             body: SingleChildScrollView(
>               child: Padding(
>                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
>                 child: Column(
>                   children: [
>                     ExpandablePanel(
>                       theme: ExpandableThemeData(
>                         headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
>                       ),
>                       header: Row(
>                         children: [
>                           Text(
>                             'Top Rated',
>                             style: TextStyle(
>                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                               fontSize: 22,
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                           SizedBox(
>                             width: 5,
>                           ),
>                           Text(
>                             'Movies',
>                             style: TextStyle(
>                               fontSize: 22,
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                         ],
>                       ),
>                       collapsed: SizedBox(
>                         height: 2,
>                       ),
>                       expanded: SizedBox(
>                         width: double.infinity,
>                         height: 200,
>                         child: ListView.separated(
>                           shrinkWrap: true,
>                           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>                           itemBuilder: (context, index) => movieItem(),
>                           separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
>                             width: 10,
>                           ),
>                           itemCount: 10,
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                     ),
>                     SizedBox(
>                       height: 10,
>                     ),
>                     ExpandablePanel(
>                       theme: ExpandableThemeData(
>                         headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
>                       ),
>                       header: Row(
>                         children: [
>                           Text(
>                             'Popular',
>                             style: TextStyle(
>                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                               fontSize: 22,
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                           SizedBox(
>                             width: 5,
>                           ),
>                           Text(
>                             'Movies',
>                             style: TextStyle(
>                               fontSize: 22,
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                         ],
>                       ),
>                       collapsed: SizedBox(
>                         height: 2,
>                       ),
>                       expanded: SizedBox(
>                         width: double.infinity,
>                         height: 200,
>                         child: ListView.separated(
>                           shrinkWrap: true,
>                           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>                           itemBuilder: (context, index) => movieItem(),
>                           separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
>                             width: 10,
>                           ),
>                           itemCount: 10,
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                     ),
>                     SizedBox(
>                       height: 10,
>                     ),
>                     ExpandablePanel(
>                       theme: ExpandableThemeData(
>                         headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
>                       ),
>                       header: Row(
>                         children: [
>                           Text(
>                             'Coming',
>                             style: TextStyle(
>                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                               fontSize: 22,
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                           SizedBox(
>                             width: 5,
>                           ),
>                           Text(
>                             'Soon',
>                             style: TextStyle(
>                               fontSize: 22,
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                         ],
>                       ),
>                       collapsed: SizedBox(
>                         height: 2,
>                       ),
>                       expanded: SizedBox(
>                         width: double.infinity,
>                         height: 200,
>                         child: ListView.separated(
>                           shrinkWrap: true,
>                           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>                           itemBuilder: (context, index) => movieItem(),
>                           separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
>                             width: 10,
>                           ),
>                           itemCount: 10,
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                     ),
>                     SizedBox(
>                       height: 10,
>                     ),
>                     ExpandablePanel(
>                       theme: ExpandableThemeData(
>                         headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
>                       ),
>                       header: Row(
>                         children: [
>                           Text(
>                             'Now',
>                             style: TextStyle(
>                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                               fontSize: 22,
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                           SizedBox(
>                             width: 5,
>                           ),
>                           Text(
>                             'Playing',
>                             style: TextStyle(
>                               fontSize: 22,
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                         ],
>                       ),
>                       collapsed: SizedBox(
>                         height: 2,
>                       ),
>                       expanded: SizedBox(
>                         width: double.infinity,
>                         height: 200,
>                         child: ListView.separated(
>                           shrinkWrap: true,
>                           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>                           itemBuilder: (context, index) => movieItem(),
>                           separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
>                             width: 10,
>                           ),
>                           itemCount: 10,
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                     ),
>                   ],
>                 ),
>               ),
>             ),
>           );
>         },
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace
`MoviesCubit()..getTopRatedData();`
with
`return MoviesCubit()..getTopRatedData();`

or replace

```
create: (BuildContext context) {
        MoviesCubit()..getTopRatedData();
      }
```

with
`create: (_) -> MoviesCubit()..getTopRatedData()`